# Merge all SKSpriteNode children into a single SKSpriteNode

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, sprite-kit

How can I take an SKSpriteNode and all its child SKSpriteNodes and merge them down into a single flattened SKSpriteNode with no children?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Create a texture of the node and create a new sprite from that texture:

```
SKTexture* tex = [self.scene.view textureFromNode:parentSprite];
SKSpriteNode* newSprite = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithTexture:tex];
```

PS: be sure not to run this in init otherwise self.view will be nil.

Comment: What is self in your example?

Comment: the node you run this code in, could be the scene or the parentSprite or just some other node subclass that has access to the combined sprite's parent node

Comment: I can't see a view property on SKSpriteNode...?

Comment: sorry, it should be self.scene.view

Comment: I can't get this working! The texture is set and has the expected size but nothing appears when I add it. Other nodes do appear.